# How to reinitialize array of struct?

Tags: c++, c++11

As we know in c++, we can reinitialize an array `arr` of size N with a value 0 as,

```
fill (arr, arr + N, 0);
```

But I need to reinitialize the array with a `struct S`,

```
struct S {
    int b[2];
}
```

The actual code is,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Dog
{
    int count[2];
};

int main(){
    ...
    Dog dogs[N];

    ...
    while (T--)
    {
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        {
            fill(dogs, dogs+N, {0});
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run into problems with `std::fill`?

Comment: use `fill` just the same

Comment: @M.M @juanchopanza using fill like, `fill (arr, arr+N, {0})` raises array. I know that the syntax doesn't make a sense, will i have to create a temporary struct variable to initialize?

Comment: I think that syntax may actually be valid.  Yes, it requires a temporary struct, but `{0}` might do  that.

Comment: @MooingDuck It gives an error `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:721:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:`

Comment: you should post the actual code you tried

Comment: @M.M I have posted the actual code

Comment: @swappy Please replace your code with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. http://ideone.com/BZLIrw.

Comment: @swappy It would be helpful if you posted the values for M,N, and T in your code, along with the output you desire, so that people we can run your example as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case:

```
struct Dog { int count[2]; };

Dog dogs[N];
```

you can use:

```
std::fill(dogs, dogs+N, Dog{});
```

The third argument to `fill` must have the right type already,  the compiler does not deduce the type from the iterator. So you cannot just use `{}` or `{0}`.

Consider using `std::begin(dogs), std::end(dogs)` instead of `dogs, dog+N` as that removes the possibility of using the wrong value for `N`.

---

I'm not sure why `fill` was designed this way, as it is certainly possible to write a function which does accept initializer list as well as normal values:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename It>
void mfill(It begin, It end, typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*begin)>::type const &v)
{
   std::fill(begin, end, v);
}

struct Dog { int count[2]; };

int main()
{
   Dog dogs[5];
   mfill(dogs, dogs+5, {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fill_n` as follows:

```
struct Dog
{
    int count[2];
};

int main(){

  Dog dogs[4] = {};
  dogs[0].count[0] = 1;

  std::fill_n(dogs, 0, Dog{});

}
```

Since `Dog` is a pod structure, you can default construct it in the last parameter of `fill_n`